# What is the Ultimate web bot platform?

Tags: ide, platform, bots

I want to make a web bot **(desktop application not web application)** which sends HTTP requests and POST data to different web pages.
What is the best solution to do such bot?
What language and IDE to use?
Witch libraries to install... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what expirience you are having.
Basicaly sending HTTP-Requests with post data should be pretty easy in most modern languages.

Personally I would use C#/.net and Visual Studio. The .net-FW has everything built in to aquire that task (e.g. [this example](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx)).

But if you are expireinced in PHP, Java or similar use that and just search for the suitable methods.